# Drawing to canvas acting buggy

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've recently started working on a side project, and experimenting with the canvas as I go. So let me explain what I want to happen:

In my JS, the `main()` function is set to an interval. During `main()` the `drawStep()` function is called. This does several things, or it should.
Sorry for the long explanation.

1. Clear the canvas, so that what is drawn doesn't stick.
2. Using a for loop, iterate through the array containing things that need to be drawn. currently only menu objects.
3. checking if the variable debug is true, if so, draw the mouse coordinates as two red lines.

However, when step 1 is done, drawing the menu objects fails, it flickers and the canvas clears to whatever color step 1 set the canvas to. When the debug `var` is set to true (through the console) Drawing the debug lines functions fine.

Here is the code blocks that matter.

Variables defined in an `init()` function, including the cookie cutter function for defining menu objects:

```
canvas = document.getElemntByID("canvas");
room = canvas.getContext("2d");
gameMode = 1; // telling the code that it is in the main menu
debug = false; //not drawing the cursor coordinates
menObj = new Array(); //an array of menu objects
mouse_x = 0; //variable set through onMouseMove event in the canvas
mouse_y = 0; //variable set through onMouseMove event in the canvas
drawList = {}; //array of menu object draw() functions, and any other item that 
 needs to be drawn during the main loop

function menu(mxpos,mypos,mwid,mhid,name, funct,drawing){
 this.x = mxpos;
 this.y = mypos;
 this.width = mwid;
 this.height = mhid;
 this.value = name;
 this.doing = funct;
 this.canDraw = drawing; //the code relies on a gameMode variable, only drawing what is allowed to when the game mode is set correctly.
 this.expand = 0; //not important, but was going to make buttons expand on mouse over
 this.maxExpand = 10; // same as above   
 //The draw function passed on to the drawList array:
 this.draw = function(){
  if (this.canDraw == gameMode){
   room.fillStyle = "rgba(150,150,150,1)";
   room.strokeStyle = "rgba(200,200,200,1)"
   room.fillRect(this.x-this.width/2,this.y-this.height/2,this.width,this.height);
   room.strokeRect(this.x-this.width/2,this.y-this.height/2,this.width,this.height);
   room.strokeStyle = "rgb(30,150,90)";
   var xoff = room.measureText(this.value).width;
   var yoff = room.measureText(this.value).height;
   room.strokeText(this.value,this.x-xoff/2,this.y-yoff/2);
  }
 }
}
```

Sample menu object creation and the for loop that adds that objects draw event to the `drawList` array:

```
var temMenVal = new menu(width/2,height/5,96,32,"Start",function(){gamemode = 1},0)
menObj.push(temMenVal);
for(var mobj in menObj){
 if (!menObj.hasOwnProperty(mobj)) continue;
  drawList[mobj]=menObj[mobj].draw(); //push wasn't working, so I improvised.
}
```

Main function, called from an interval timer.

```
function main(){
  drawStep();
}
```

This is the draw function, where my issue is:

```
function drawStep(){
 //the latest attempt at a fix, instead of using a clearRect(), which failed.
 //I tried this
 room.save()
 room.fillStyle="black";
 room.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
 room.restore();
 for (var n in drawList){
  room.save();
  if (!drawList.hasOwnProperty(n)) continue;
   if (n<drawList.length){
    drawList[n](); //calling the draw() from the nested menu object, it DOES work, when the above clear to black is NOT called
   }
  room.restore();
 }
 if (debug == true){
  room.beginPath();
  room.strokeStyle="rgb(255,0,0)";
  room.moveTo(mouse_x,0); //variable set through onmousemove event in the canvas
  room.lineTo(mouse_x,height);
  room.moveTo(0,mouse_y); //variable set through onmousemove event in the canvas
  room.lineTo(width,mouse_y);
  room.stroke();
  room.closePath();  
 }
}
```

I can't figure out why it keeps clearing to black, when the menu objects SHOULD be drawn after the clear. Like I said way up there, setting debug to true DOES draw the cursor coordinates correctly.

Comment: I have found the problem, and worked in a solution to the code.
As it turns out, all of the drawList array was empty. I have reworked the code to draw right
from the menObj array. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your draw list, try removing the two parens in `menObj[mobj].draw()`

What it seems like is that you are actually *calling* the method instead of passing it as a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but when I remove the two parenthesis from the end, nothing but the debug is drawn (tested with debug = true) Just the black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try init menu with **drawing** = 1 and edit code as Hylianpuffball point out. I think  this.canDraw == gameMode is always false.